# Can i search for all product in search

Tags: php, magento

i'm looking for a way in magento search to display all products. it's for a quick search by attribute purpose, i implemented GET filters which adds attributes to filter to collection list, and i want to apply them to the full products collection.

```
if(count($_GET) > 0 && $isSearchPage){
$_productCollection = $_productCollection->clear()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$suffix = array();
foreach($_GET as $filter => $value){
    $suffix[$filter] = $value;
    if($filter != 'q' && $filter != 'limit' && $filter != 'p'){
        $_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter($filter,$value);
    }
}
}
```

So far i tried

```
/catalogsearch/result/?q=%
/catalogsearch/result/?q=*
```

q=% return results, but not all of them. Is there a way to do what i'm trying to achieve ? Or am I heading in the wrong direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento alreay have Advanced search feature where you can search the products based on the attribute .You can see the demo of this feature [here](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/catalogsearch/advanced/) .Maybe you can extend it according to your need.

Comment: customizing catalogsearch/advanced/results is indeed way more relevant, i wanted to stick to this filter system i already made, but advanced search works like a charm. Thanks